# Android: How to change color of the bottom line in the EditText for API 19

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having trouble changing the color of the bottom line of the EditText.
I have tried:

```
 <style name="MyEditTextTheme">
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#F0DDAA</item>
</style>
```

but apparently it only works on API 22 of my emulator, when i tried lowering to API 19, it doesn't have any effect. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to support older versions use this style, parent must be `@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText`

```
<style name="MyEditTextTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>
</style>

//your edit text  
<EditText 
    ....
    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme" />
```

**IMPT** : Your class must extend **`AppCompatActivity`** otherwise theme won't work.